# Retrieving data from different models

Tags: cakephp, model

I've been trying to display the data from different model in the same page but still can't get it working.
This is the relationship betweens models

Customer hasMany Job

Job belongsTo Customer

Job hasMany Jobtask

Jobtask belongsTo Job

Jobtask hasMany Jobtasksvehicle

Jobtasksvehicle belongsTo Jobtask and Vehicle

Vehicle hasMany Jobtasksvehicle

This is my job controller

```
    function sch($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid job', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $job = $this->Job->find('first', array(
'conditions' => array('Job.id' => $id),
'contain' => array('Customer',
    'Jobtask' => array(
        'Jobtasksvehicle' => array(
            'Vehicle'
         ),
     ),
),
```

));

What I've to do is display data from Customer, Job, Jobtask, Jobtasksvehicle, Vehicle models.
I can get the data display from Customer, Job and Jobtask but not from Jobtasksvehicle and Vehicle models. I want to display each vehicle (vehiclemodel) assigned to each jobtask.

This is where I want to display jobtask and Vehicle models in the same table.

```
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($job['Jobtask'] as $jobtask):
        $class = null;
        if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
            $class = ' class="altrow"';
        }
    ?>
    <tr<?php echo $class;?>>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['job_id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['rate_id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['type'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['date'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['starttime'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['timeband'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['settlement'];?></td>       
        <td><?php echo $job['Vehicle']['vehiclemodel'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

?>

Comment: The find function seems to be correct. Did you try to debug the $job variable? Is it possible that the record which you looking doesn't have Jobtasksvehicle AND Vehicle associated?

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be fine, you need to put the find in recursive = 3, like this

```
  $job = $this->Job->find('first', array(
      'conditions' => array('Job.id' => $id),
      'recursive' => 3,
      'contain' => array('Customer',
            'Jobtask' => array(
               'Jobtasksvehicle' => array(
               'Vehicle'
                ),
            ),
       ),
   ));
```

but still the containable behaviour should calculate the recursive automatic, Make sure you are loading the containable bahaviour.

Check the book out about [containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable)

Also check if the sql queries are being done, if the sql queries appear you may need to specify the fields (you may want to use Job.* o Vehicle.* to get all fields...)